# Google Sheets - Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet, permission-denied

So first of all, I am completely new to scripting so I would be very thankful to any help and easy explanations!

I am currently writing a script for Google Sheets which should delete several rows in different Worksheets of different Spreadsheets.

The script I have is very simple and probably not very elegant, but it kinda works..

When I tested to delete rows in spreadsheet b from spreadsheet a it worked.
But when trying to delete rows in spreadsheets b,c,d,e etc. from spreadsheet a, I encounter the following error:

*Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets*

Here is my code:

```
function RunJuan() {
 
const sshp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 const wshp = sshp.getSheetByName("Hyde Park Source")
 
const sscr = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1NoWJoTXGAaXbh-uvHGig3VuKWhKc3xUgVWDHwqve2AY")
  const wscr =  sscr.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")
 
const ssln = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1H6V81ENaC6a3XiLoolzld-nuEYQQLUkTj0Bo5ZSxhR0")
  const wsln =  ssln.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")
 
const ssmc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1FamQaP0konp87vg6ey6XHKlA_tiywLCmxRr4N7XLojc")
  const wsmc =  ssmc.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")
 
const ssre = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheets/d/1jPUZNh_URRw1aLmK-5q4ioXPcwrtu9HIhZk5mEEjwvw")
  const wsre =  ssre.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")
 
const ssro = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1o29Cc69xmQCrKxHYMYvF-yWDYvE3-LZfF1dsLVxE2mI")
   const wsro =  ssro.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")
 
const sssab = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qZM3lsjOAy56ZbllTz5GUz88LQnkE8MNN3fGJ4gb5OA")
   const wssab =  sssab.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")
 
const ssst = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1cji19ayNrTfeERtBx81kVLCHffZBxj5aK6B0Cb3EP9Y")
   const wsst =  ssst.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")
 
const ssww = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1o29Cc69xmQCrKxHYMYvF-yWDYvE3-LZfF1dsLVxE2mI")
   const wsww =  ssww.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")
 
 
 
 
  wshp.deleteRow(2)
  wshp.deleteRow(2)
  wshp.deleteRow(2)
  wshp.deleteRow(2)
  wshp.deleteRow(2)
  wshp.deleteRow(2)
  wshp.deleteRow(2)
  wshp.deleteRow(2)
  wshp.deleteRow(2)
 
  wscr.deleteRow(2)
  wscr.deleteRow(2)
  wscr.deleteRow(2)
  wscr.deleteRow(2)
  wscr.deleteRow(2)
  wscr.deleteRow(2)
  wscr.deleteRow(2)
  wscr.deleteRow(2)
  wscr.deleteRow(2)
 
  wsln.deleteRow(2)
  wsln.deleteRow(2)
  wsln.deleteRow(2)
  wsln.deleteRow(2)
  wsln.deleteRow(2)
  wsln.deleteRow(2)
  wsln.deleteRow(2)
  wsln.deleteRow(2)
  wsln.deleteRow(2)
 
  wsmc.deleteRow(2)
  wsmc.deleteRow(2)
  wsmc.deleteRow(2)
  wsmc.deleteRow(2)
  wsmc.deleteRow(2)
  wsmc.deleteRow(2)
  wsmc.deleteRow(2)
  wsmc.deleteRow(2)
  wsmc.deleteRow(2)
 
  wsre.deleteRow(2)
  wsre.deleteRow(2)
  wsre.deleteRow(2)
  wsre.deleteRow(2)
  wsre.deleteRow(2)
  wsre.deleteRow(2)
  wsre.deleteRow(2)
  wsre.deleteRow(2)
  wsre.deleteRow(2)
 
 
  wsro.deleteRow(2)
  wsro.deleteRow(2)
  wsro.deleteRow(2)
  wsro.deleteRow(2)
  wsro.deleteRow(2)
  wsro.deleteRow(2)
  wsro.deleteRow(2)
  wsro.deleteRow(2)
  wsro.deleteRow(2)
 
  wssab.deleteRow(2)
  wssab.deleteRow(2)
  wssab.deleteRow(2)
  wssab.deleteRow(2)
  wssab.deleteRow(2)
  wssab.deleteRow(2)
  wssab.deleteRow(2)
  wssab.deleteRow(2)
  wssab.deleteRow(2)
 
  wsst.deleteRow(2)
  wsst.deleteRow(2)
  wsst.deleteRow(2)
  wsst.deleteRow(2)
  wsst.deleteRow(2)
  wsst.deleteRow(2)
  wsst.deleteRow(2)
  wsst.deleteRow(2)
  wsst.deleteRow(2)
 
  wsww.deleteRow(2)
  wsww.deleteRow(2)
  wsww.deleteRow(2)
  wsww.deleteRow(2)
  wsww.deleteRow(2)
  wsww.deleteRow(2)
  wsww.deleteRow(2)
  wsww.deleteRow(2)
  wsww.deleteRow(2)
};
```

I googled but I honestly don't really understand the different solutions the people give.
So I would really appreciate any beginner-friendly phrased advice :D

Comment: Are you the owner of the sheets you're calling?

Comment: Yes, I created them with the same google Account

Comment: At a minimum, reduce your code. are you trying to delete a range of rows?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You will get that error if you run the code by calling it as a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) from a formula in a spreadsheet cell. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @pgSystemTester yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @doubleunary I try to have a button with a macro assigned to delete the rows. Does that answer your question, I'm not sure if I understand it right..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but it begs to be pointed out that you could reduce your number of lines of code by a colossal amount. It appears you are doing the same thing over and over, but with just two variables... the `ID` and `sheet name` (maybe the sheet name is always the same, at which point it's even easier).

If you hard-code these inputs into a constant array, you could create a far more concise procedure with a [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) as shown below. Another benefit is that it would simplify any future modifications. Again, this (probably) won't resolve your issue, but reducing lines of code is always a good step when facing a problem.

```
function RunJuan() {
  //list all the id's and corresponding sheet names
  const allFiles = [
    ["1NoWJoTXGAaXbh-uvHGig3VuKWhKc3xUgVWDHwqve2AY", "Form responses 1"],
    ["1H6V81ENaC6a3XiLoolzld-nuEYQQLUkTj0Bo5ZSxhR0", "Form responses 1"],
    ["1o29Cc69xmQCrKxHYMYvF-yWDYvE3-LZfF1dsLVxE2mI", "Form responses 1"]
  ];

  //loop through your allFiles array
  for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
    var aFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(allFiles[i][0]);
    var ws = aFile.getSheetByName(allFiles[i][1]);
    //starting at row 2, delete 9 rows i.e. rows(2:10)
    ws.deleteRows(2, 9);
  }
}
```